# IPython solarized?

Tags: ipython, color-scheme, spyder

I'm running Spyder and with Pschelo's [spyder solarized theme](https://github.com/pshchelo/spyder-color-solarized), but the console, including IPython console, is not affected by the IDE theme. How can I tweak the default color theme in IPython so that it uses [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) colours?

Comment: That works on either a light or dark background? Can it be made from terminal colours? We're actually looking for a better default colour scheme: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2281 .

As for the files, I think `IPython.core.excolors` and `IPython.core.prompts` are good places to start looking.

Comment: By terminal colours do you mean ANSI colours? Is IPython supposed to handle only 16 colours?

Comment: Yep, solarized is available in 16 colours (see their [Xresources](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/blob/master/xresources-colors-solarized/Xresources)). I'm just finding it hard to change IPython.core.coloransi accordingly and make it work on Windows.

Comment: I think most Linux terminals can do 256 colours; I'm not sure about Windows. I see you've commented on the bug report, you're also welcome to discuss it on the mailing list http://mail.scipy.org/mailman/listinfo/ipython-dev (where Jörgen, our Windows expert, should see it)

Comment: Console2 (in Windows) uses 16 colours, but it seems that IPython's source code also restricts it to 16 colours (but again, I could be wrong).

Comment: By the looks of it, [these are the colours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) we can work with. It looks like Xresources modifies that set, which I think we should steer clear of.

Comment: IPython does use Solarized colours when I run it on Console2, and Console2 is using its pallette. So maybe the missing functionality is in Spyder, not IPython.

Comment: Ah, in Spyder what you're using is a Qt widget. There's a way to style that with CSS, although I'm not sure how you can do that within Spyder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 2.1 there is no way to change the color scheme to use the ones defined for the Editor. There are just two different versions: with white and dark background (and I don't know if they are still working correctly)

However, we plan to use fine grained color schemes for IPython in version 2.2 (because as Thomas pointed out, IPython now can handle them correctly).